# Row reducing with unknown values

Tags: linear-algebra

This is the first time I take linear algebra, so pardon my seemingly trivial question:

How do I form zeroes under the leading entry if there is an unknown in the same column?

\begin{matrix}
  k & 1 & 1 &\big| \quad 1\\
  1 & k & 1 &\big| \quad 1\\
  1 & 1 & k &\big| \quad 1\\
 \end{matrix}

Suppose I swap rows $1$ and $2$. How do I change the k in the first column to a zero?

Answer (score 0):

After swapping rows $1$ and $2$ you get
$$\begin{bmatrix}1 & k & 1 & 1 \\ k & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & k & 1\end{bmatrix}$$
so then do the row operation where you subtract $k$ times row $1$ from row $2$.

Comment: Thank you! I don't know why it didn't occur to me that I could multiply by k.